# Solving $T^2 = -\kappa\, \mathrm{Tr}\, (\log(e^{i T \hat{H}_0} \hat{O}) )^2$ equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras

Is there a way to solve the equation: $T^2 = -\kappa\, \mathrm{Tr}\, (\log(e^{i T \hat{H}_0} \hat{O}) )^2$ for $T$?

Here $\kappa$ is an arbitrary positive constant, $\hat{H}_0 \in \mathfrak{su}(N)$ and $\hat{O} \in SU(N)$. $\log$ is the principle matrix log.
I'm only interested in positive $T$ solutions.

I have solved it in the case that $e^{iT\hat{H}_0}$ and $\hat{O}$ commute, the answer is obtained from the quadratic formula and is not an especially pleasing form.

Comment: What are $r$ and $T$?

Comment: The $Tr$ together means the matrix trace.

Comment: OK. That means that $T$ is a scalar. I took the liberty and edited the equation in your question.

Comment: you want a closed form solution without specifying $H_0$ and $O$? not much hope for that...

Comment: You seem to be missing an open parenthesis. I'm guessing it's before the log?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Perhaps there could be a closed form solution in terms of spectra of $H_0$ and $\widehat{O}$. Since the OP claims that he obtained some formula in the case when these two operators commute, it is probably time to investigate spectral mapping theorem in the context of functional calculus in several variables for non-commuting operators. ;)

Comment: @user44191: Thanks for spotting my error. I've deleted the parenthesis.

Comment: We can get rid of $\kappa$; let $T' = T/\sqrt\kappa$ and $H'_0 = H_0/\sqrt\kappa$.

Comment: Also, when you say the square of the log, do you mean the Killing form on two copies of that log?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: @VítTuček --- if $H_0$ and $O$ commute, the trace depends only on the $N$ eigenvalues of each of these two matrices; once you abandon that, the eigenvectors enter as well so knowing the spectra of $H_0$ and $O$ will not suffice.